# Continuous function, that satisfies $f(f(x)) = x$ on $[0, 1]$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Prove that if function $f: [0,1] \to [0,1] $ is continuous and $f(0) = 0, f(1) = 1, f(f(x)) = x \ \forall x \in [0,1]$, then $ f(x) = x \ \forall x \in [0, 1]$.
I have tried to prove this by contradiction, but all I could get is that if for some $a$ $f(a) \neq a$, then the function should have a "symmetrical" point $(f(a), a)$